# Converting time in integer to MIN:SEC

Tags: r, time, lubridate, posixct

I am using this code to find a difference between two times:

```
station_data.avg$duration[i] = if_else(station_data.avg$swath[i] != 0, round(
    difftime(station_data.avg$end[i], station_data.avg$start[i], units = "mins"),
    3
  ), 0)
```

But the output is 3.116667 and I want the output to be in the format Min:sec so 3:18

I tried

```
station_data.avg$duration[i]= as.character(times(station_data.avg$duration[i] / (24 * 60 )))
```

and was hoping that would work but it did not

Comment: Please share some example data so that you can get better, faster help. Try eating your question and paste the output of `dput(station.data.avg)`

Comment: Have you tried the function `as.Date()` before the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chron` package to convert fraction of the minute (ie, x.25 indicating 25% of a minute) into x.15 indicating out of 60 seconds (15/60 = 25). An example is below, but if you edit your question to make it reproducible, I can provide more specific help.

Data

```
a <- Sys.time()
b <- Sys.time() + 60 * 3 + 15 # add 3 min 15 seconds
```

Code

```
difftime(b, a, units = "min")
# Time difference of 3.250006 mins

chron::times(as.numeric(difftime(b, a, units = "days")))
# [1] 00:03:15
```

Note the change to `units = "days"` in this context.

You could further parse this out by wrapping this in `lubridate::hms`:

```
lubridate::hms(
  chron::times(as.numeric(difftime(b, a, units = "days")))
)

# [1] "3M 15S"
```

Comment: Great! @ChloeEggert if it works, please click the little checkmark by the answers others know this is a working solution. It helps clean up the site and lets others focus on unanswered questions. Glad it worked!